# Android/Parse- How to handle multiple callbacks from ParseQuery

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, callback, parse-platform

I need to call 4 queries like that before start my MainActivity.
I would like to know how to handle multiple callbacks running in background and just start the MainActivity when all the callbacks return the data that I want.

Can anyone provide some code of how to do that?

```
ParseQuery query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Ranking"); 
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(List list, ParseException e) {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not want to wait to display your activity, you may get an ANR... but I assume you will display a "loading" message or something.

As for your multiple callbacks, if you have a predefined set of callbacks, you could use boolean flags that are checked off or use a simple counter, then do a check on either one in your callback. For example:

myCallback.queryDone();

Then:

```
public myCallback implements MyCallback() {
    private static volatile int count = 0;

    public void queryDone() {
        count++;
        if (count == 4) {
            // start activity here
        }
    }
}
```

If you have an indeterminate number of callbacks (e.g. it could 3 or 10), then you need to build a queue or make the systems suggested above more complex to handle the variety.

Comment: Nice approach, however just watch for synchronization, this may cause the condition to never be met, defining the counter as a member and volatile should do in the case, and it's an easier and cleaner solution.

Comment: @Toguard - good points, although I assumed only one myCallback would be created; however, your points prevent the problem regardless of implementation and so I edited my post. Thanks